# setState (array) entries are disappearing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, chat

In the following example, `User2`'s messages are getting erased from the state as soon as the `User1` sends a message.

`User1` sends a message, it gets displayed on screen. As soon as `User2` replies, `User1`'s messages disappear.

I'm persuaded it's a React `setState` mistake but I've followed the `react-native-chat-ui`'s docs as much as possible but somehow there is something going wrong and I cannot put my finger on it.

Here's a video of the bug in action: https://streamable.com/rxbx18

Thank you.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Chat, MessageType } from '@flyerhq/react-native-chat-ui'
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'

const uuidv4 = () => {
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, (c) => {
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)
    const v = c === 'x' ? r : (r % 4) + 8
    return v.toString(16)
  })
};

const user    = { id: uuidv4(), firstName: 'User1' };
const chatbot = { id: uuidv4(), firstName: 'User2' };

const App = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<MessageType.Any[]>([])

  const addMessage = (message: MessageType.Any) => {
    setMessages([message, ...messages]);
  };

  const handleSendPress = (message: MessageType.PartialText) => {
    // display user message
    const textMessage: MessageType.Text = {
      author   : user,
      createdAt: Date.now(),
      id       : uuidv4(),
      text     : message.text,
      type     : 'text',
    };
    addMessage(textMessage);

    // display bot message
    // NOTE: adding a timeout so that you can see user's message for a second...
    setTimeout(() => {
      const chatbotTextMessage: MessageType.Text = {
        author   : chatbot,
        createdAt: Date.now(),
        id       : uuidv4(),
        text     : `Response that will erase user's messages...`,
        type     : 'text',
      };
      addMessage(chatbotTextMessage);
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
    <Chat
      messages={messages}
      showUserNames={true}
      onSendPress={handleSendPress}
      user={user}
    />
  </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Try `setMessages(prev => [message, ...prev])` ?. Also your video link is not reachable

Comment: IT FIXED IT! But why? could you post an answer and explain why? Thanks so much!

Comment: Well, whenever you update React's state value which depends on a previous state, you should use [`useReducer`](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/should-i-usestate-or-usereducer) or at-least [functional `useState` updater](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state)

Comment: From React docs: 
```Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread syntax:```
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate